# Increment the number under the curser in vim editor by a pattern

Tags: vim, record, auto-increment

Is it possible to increment the number under the cursor in vim editor by a pattern. For example I need it like this:

Before Edit:

```
15 Apple
15 Orange
15 Mango
15 Grape
15 Pineapple
15 Tomato
15 Plum
15 Cherry
```

After Edit

```
18 Apple
19 Orange
20 Mango
21 Grape
22 Pineapple
23 Tomato
24 Plum
25 Cherry
```

Means in first **line** its incremented by 3, 2nd **line** by 4, 3rd **line** by 5 and so on.
I am thinking of **recording** and **play back**.
But each **line** the incremented value is incremented by one. (pattern like **3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, etc,.**)

Please let me know any one have the solution.

If we can achieve like below is also appreciated.

```
16 Apple
17 Orange
18 Mango
19 Grape
20 Pineapple
21 Tomato
22 Plum
23 Cherry
```

Pattern starts with 1. (patterns is **1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc,.**)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Comment: You'll have to customize VIM a little with a script or macro, but a good start is to look at `:help ctrl-a`.

Comment: Hi all,

Please dont misunderstand me. I know the how to increment (ctrl-a) or decrement (ctrl-x) the number under the cursor with a specific value. But here the case is different. I have thousands of lines in my file. and each line I need to increment the number under the cursor with a value which is one increment than the previous line.
Here duplication wont work because each line is entirely different.
the code I posted is an example which just describe what I need. Actual case is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

except for variable to control the `+1`, there is another way to do it. First take a look the line number of the first line in your text block, say it was `7`, then you can:

```
:7,$s/^\d\+\ze/\=submatch(0)+3+line('.')-7/
```

For example, if it is the first line, you can change the `7` into `1`:

```
 :%s/^\d\+\ze/\=submatch(0)+3+line('.')-1/
```

Answer (score 1):

use a var save count, and combine g and s

`:let n=15+3|g/^\d\+/exec "s//".n|let n=n+1`

another way, use (ctrl-a)
first move to 15, change to 17. then `"ayiw` save to register a.
then you can record macro, use:

`qqciw<C-r>a<esc><C-a>"ayiwjq`, last repeat macro q `@q`